# Load array declaration from a text file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Before posting, I've read through suggested similar questions, but couldn't find an answer.

I have an array declaration stored in a text.txt file. Let's say the array declaration looks something like this:

```
["content1-1", ["content2-1", "content2-1"]]
```

I want to load this as an array into a variable in JavaScript.

This is what I tried:

```js
var data = []

 function loadSOAFile(chineseCharacter) {
  var textfileFileName = "text.txt"
  var rawSOAFile=new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawSOAFile.open("GET",textfileFileName);
  rawSOAFile.onload=function(){
       console.log(rawSOAFile.responseText);
   data = rawSOAFile.responseText
  }
  rawSOAFile.send();
  
  setTimeout(function() {
                     document.getElementById("debuggingconsole").innerHTML = data[0]
    }, 200);
}
```

However, when I call the function, instead of writing "content1-1" it writes "[", so clearly it loads the variable as a string rather than an array.

Is there a cleaver way to load it as an array declaration? I don't deal with JS all that often, so answers providing a little bit more context would be most appreciated.

Comment: what is a "textile" ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, a "textile" was clearly a misspelled "text file." Luckily, kvsm here came up with a perfect solution to the problem before I even had time to correct it. Kudos Kvsm for not getting distracted by minutiae.

Comment: Instead of using `setTimeout()` to access `data[0]`, perform the assignment to `innerHTML` within the `onload` callback so that you're not introducing a [race-conditon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) in your code.

Comment: @Tyro I am not familiar with English and I have tried in vain to understand if your typographical fault hid a semantic subtlety giving a particular meaning to your question. It was not a "distraction" for me, and I feel   you're mocking me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is formatted as you describe, then it's valid JSON. You can retrieve the values from the string by parsing it as such:

```
data = JSON.parse(rawSOAFile.responseText)
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you so much, works like a charm.

Comment: @Tyro if the answer solved your problem, please click to accept the answer.

Comment: I’ve just “ticked it off.” I hope that’s what you meant by “accept the answer.”